# failed to load css bootstrap js on localhost when page refresh

Tags: javascript, laravel, apache, server, bootstrap-5

Whenever i access my localhost laravel project first time it executes fine but when i refresh it then i am getting not found 404 errors css js etc and webpage layout change.in short bootstrap js files can't loaded.i tried to enable css map and js map in chromium setting but still getting 404 errors.thanks in advance stackoverflow

[image]

**note:**  ** npm run dev ** && ** npm run dev ** which i have already executed still no change in error.

**EDITED**

When i successfully load my page then i get blow image

[image: success]

When i page refresh OR f5 then **two css** missing with 404 errors please see below error page

[image: two css files is not loaded when refresh]

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-ot-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) to see how you can improve your question.

Comment: Can we see the HTML source that these errors are coming from?

Comment: @AndyPreston i don't share html code cause that's not html code issues

Comment: @AndyPreston if any problem in coding then why first time execute my project sucessfully...i getting error when i press f5 in browser

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to clear the cache? You can try executing these commands.

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan view:clear
```

Comment: i alread tried but no change..i think that's not laravel issues